# Cannot get / in Node.js app how to redirect?

Tags: node.js

I have written app.get() for all url's which has a function. Is there a way to call a function if URL is not defined?

Angular has an otherwise method, similarly is there any other function to redirect undefined URL's in Node.js?

```
app.post('/registration',register);

app.get('/user',UserRegistration);
```

If i call a /users which is not written what function to be called to redirect it to index.html page.

Comment: Do you use bare-metal Node.js, or a framework (Express, Angular...)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

more info [here](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.use)

Comment: This is using Express.js, I think you should make it more clear.

Comment: I have tried using middleware but the thing is how to specify Node to exclude URL's? If my clients goes to an URL which is not defined I should redirect to res.redirect('/');

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js without framework, your code should look like:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');

function parse (req, callback) {
    var path = [],
        u;

    u = url.parse(req);
    path = u.pathname.split('/');

    callback(path);
}

function send_cat2 (req, res, n) {
    //Generate /cat2/n
    //Send page n
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = parse(req);
    if(path[0] === 'cat1') {
        if(path[1] === 'page1') {
            // /cat1/page1
        } else if (path[1] === 'page2') {
            // /cat1/page2
        } else {
            // 404
        }
    } else if (path[0] === 'cat2') {
        // /cat2/n
        send_cat2(req, res, parseInt(path[1]));
    } else {
        // 404
    }
});
```

Comment: you saying to put all the URL's in a if ? The processing time delay will take much if i use 250 URL's..

Comment: You can optimize the if/else to avoid a lot of the overhead, after that, you can use function passing to avoid the if/else.

Comment: Updated to put example of improved if/else, and treat similar page. I d like to point out that this is pure node.js, and as of the exmple of your question, you use express.